# How to put all column in Room?

Tags: android, android-room

I have dao with this query

```
@Query("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO SomeTable (*) VALUES(:someEntities) WHERE is_favourite_entity = 0;")
void insertAll(List<SomeEntity> someEntities);
```

But in `Sometable (*)` i have syntax error.

It is possible put all data with meta char * , or how can i achieve this?

Comment: What tutorial or documentation are you reading which tells you to use this code/syntax?

Comment: official documentation

Comment: Removing the offending `(*)` should fix the problem.

Comment: I can't find the official documentation which uses this syntax. Could you link me to it?

Comment: @KlingKlang i know))) But i want to put all column in SomeTable , because column's more than 15

Comment: You can't invent your own syntax just because you're lazy.

Comment: Please show me example , where i can see "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO with WHERE condition" , i can't find in google

Comment: It seems you need to study the `REPLACE INTO` command. Google keywords: `replace into sqlite`